# Google map Marker customization by google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using google maps for my map and showcasing the markers in the maps, As I was using the mapBOX earlier the mapmarkers we are showcased as  follows are displayed in map.

But by using google maps for markers I am using google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE for rounded markers.

But my case few times i want to make use of SQUARED MARKERS with some text inside marker.

How can i achieve this, Is there any special library i have to use for this case.

Please refer this screenshot, and guide on this.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define custom paths for [google.maps.Symbols](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols#custom_paths).  Below is an example based off the [example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-custom).  You can add [a single character "label" to the marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#marker_labels).

```
var square = {
    path: 'M -2,-2 2,-2 2,2 -2,2 z', // 'M -2,0 0,-2 2,0 0,2 z',
    strokeColor: '#F00',
    fillColor: '#F00',
    fillOpacity: 1,
    scale: 5
  };
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: 21.5, lng: 153.027},
    map: map,
    icon: square,
      label: {
      text:"X",
      fontWeight: "bold"
    }
  });
```

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: {
      lat: 21.5,
      lng: 153.027
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });

  // Define the custom symbols. All symbols are defined via SVG path notation.
  var square = {
    path: 'M -2,-2 2,-2 2,2 -2,2 z', // 'M -2,0 0,-2 2,0 0,2 z',
    strokeColor: '#F00',
    fillColor: '#F00',
    fillOpacity: 1,
    scale: 5
  };
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: 21.5,
      lng: 153.027
    },
    map: map,
    icon: square,
    label: {
      text: "X",
      fontWeight: "bold"
    }

  });
  var toggle = false;
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
    if (!toggle) {
      this.setLabel({
        text: "X",
        color: "white",
        fontWeight: "bold"
      });
    } else {
      this.setLabel({
        text: "X",
        color: "black",
        fontWeight: "bold"
      });
    }
    toggle = !toggle;
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```